# Show that the limit of a function equals the delta function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I have been struggling with the following problem and any help / good place to start would be appreciated.

Show,

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  f_\epsilon (x-x_0) = \delta(x-x_0)$$

when

$$f_\epsilon =  {(2\epsilon)^{-1}}   for |x|\leqslant \epsilon $$

and

$$f_\epsilon =  0 \     \ \text{otherwise.} $$

Comment: Have you considered this as a post on [math.se] instead, or checked for duplicates there

Comment: If $\varphi(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \langle f_\epsilon, \varphi \rangle= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_\epsilon(x) \varphi(x)dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2 \epsilon} \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \varphi(x)dx = \varphi(0) = \langle \delta, \varphi \rangle$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A physicist approach is to notice that the function $f_{\epsilon}$ goes to infinity when $\epsilon\to 0$ while the integral over $\Bbb{R}$ is equal to $1$ and a physicist concludes that the limit is $\delta_0$.

Now I am not a physicist so let's look at it from the distribution theory angle. $f_\epsilon$ is locally intégrable so it defines a distribution that is a continuous linear operator on the test functions $\varphi\in\mathcal{D}(\Bbb{R})$ ($\mathcal{C}^\infty$ with compact support)

$$\langle f_\epsilon,\varphi\rangle=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f_\epsilon(x)\cdot \varphi(x)dx={1\over 2\epsilon}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\varphi(x)dx $$

for $\epsilon$ small enough.

Now we can prove that

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}{1\over 2\epsilon}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\varphi(x)dx=\varphi(0)$$

And in distribution theory delta is the linear form $\delta_0:\varphi\to\varphi(0)$

Comment: That's not enough for a mathematician. But nice try.

Comment: From my personal view, the physicist approach is much easier to understand.